# how to stop JTable for user interaction?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using a `JTable` with 4 columns, How to set `JTable`, to select a row but the user should not change the values of the row?

```
Jtable.setEnabled(false);
```

this statement doesnt work for me, because user can't select the row.

How can I replace this code with ur answers?

```
public void setModel()
{
    String[] colNames = {"Name","Email","Department","Status"};
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames,500);
    table.setModel(model);

    String insert = "select * from " + deptName;

    try
    {
        conn = ac.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        int row = 0;   
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String[] rowData = new String[5];
            for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
            {
                rowData[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
            }
            model.setValueAt(rowData[0], row, 0);
            model.setValueAt(rowData[1], row, 1);
            model.setValueAt(rowData[2], row, 2);                
            model.setValueAt(rowData[3], row, 3);                
            row++;  

        }
    }catch(SQLException s){}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(rs != null){rs.close();}
            if(stmt != null){stmt.close();}
            if(conn != null) {conn.close();}
        }
        catch(SQLException e){}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set model for the table and override `isCellEditable` method

```
jtable.setModel(new TableModel() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you created your table model, you will want to override the [`TableModel#isCellEditable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) and return `false` for all the cells you want to be non-editable

Check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Extend the DefaultTableModel kinda like this

```
private class NoCellEditTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
       //all cells false
       return false;
    }
}
```

Then set it to your JTable

Answer (score 1):

Biased me can't resist suggesting to use JXTable (in the [SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net): it comes with support to configure the editability on the view, both per-column and per-table

```
// to disable editing for a particular column
table.getColumnExt(columnIndex).setEditable(false);
// to disable editing for the complete table
table.setEditable(false);
```